# Why does Maven want to download a module from a remote repository

Tags: java, maven, repository

Given the following modules in my pom.xml

```
<modules>
  <module>core</module>
  <module>middle-layer</module>
  <module>top-layer</module>
<modules>
```

Where top-layer depends on middle-layer which depends on core.

When I run `clean install` it will build and install core and middle-layer successfully, but not top-layer. It tries to download middle-layer from a remote repository instead of using the freshly built one in the local repository.

I do have a custom remote repository specified in my pom.xml:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>custom</id>
        <url>http://someaddress/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Why does it want to grab middle-layer from the remote repository?

Currently, everything is in SNAPSHOT-mode.

Middle layer dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Top layer dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>middle-layer</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

They all inherent their versions from the parent (currently at 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT) and I'm calling install from the parent pom.

Comment: Have you correctly defined the dependencies between those modules? Have you called the `mvn install` from the root parent ? Why are using repositories in you pom file. Better use a repository manager and put that into settings.xml

Comment: Could you include the dependency part of `top-layer` and the definition part of the `middle-layer`?

Comment: I was asking only because it should work as you laid it out. Check the definition up on top of middle layer with the name and the version or parent. If you still can't see it you'll have to post the whole thing somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

It was a typical problem between keyboard and chair.

The middle-layer is actually historically a WAR, not a JAR, that is to say: it includes some classes I needed in my top-layer. (It's not really called middle-layer of course).
So top-layer searches for middle-layer.jar and can't find it (because it's a WAR).

So I have to refactor some stuff to get the things I need from middle-layer into a new library JAR and make both middle-layer and top-layer depend on that instead.

Sorry to waste your time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maven frequently prints messages about downloading things that it is not, in fact, downloading. It is considering the possibility that there is a newer snapshot available remotely than the last one build locally. This is why uploading snapshots is often a really bad idea.